# Is there a way to convert MS 2010 Equation to Object in MS Equation 3.0?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, equations, docx, equation-editor

I have a lot of equations (for faculty) written in MS Equation (button from right side) and saved it in `.docx` format.

All good and the best until my professor told me that he has MS 2003 and I have to convert from `docx` to `doc` format and the equations must be editable.

I don't have enough time to rewrite all the equations in MS Equation 3.0.

Is there a way to convert from MS Equation to MS Equation 3.0 Object to be recognized and editable in Word 2003?